# Each time I boot the system it start "scanning disk for errors"

Tags: boot, fsck

My system is scanning the disk for errors every time I boot the system, so I have to wait until it completes or press <kbd>C</kbd> to cancel it. The system operates normally afterwards but I would like to stop the filesystem check at every boot. How do I do this?

Comment: And describe how you shut down the system.

Comment: I really hope this is the problem you are facing, if that's the case then it has an easy solution.

Comment: **Voters**, I think the question is clear enough.

Comment: Voters who're closing this: Please be aware the question is clear, however you should NOT disable the filesystem check when it says to do it, it's there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use the disk utility and look at the smart data to see if your hard drive is starting
to act up.  Just go to the dash and type: disk